# Using elcloud_s3 to upload to files to S3 i

Tags: erlang, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I am trying to use the erlang module erlcloud_s3 to upload a file to S3. For some reason that I have not been able to work out it does not work. I have included my code (with keys removed of course) and the response that I get when I try to run this. Can someone tell me what I am missing (or if there is a better AWS package for Erlang that actually has some docs or examples?)

```
-module(compose).

-define('ACCESS_KEY',       "********************").
-define('SECRET_ACCESS_KEY',    "****************************************").
-define('BUCKET',       "zacharykessin"). 

-export([upload/2, upload_file/2]).

upload_file(Key, Path) ->    
    R = file:read_file(Path),
    {ok, Binary} = R,
    upload(Key, Binary).


upload(Key, Value) ->
    A = erlcloud_ec2:configure(?ACCESS_KEY, ?SECRET_ACCESS_KEY),
    error_logger:info_msg("~p:~p Settng up AWS ~p to S3 ~n", 
              [?MODULE, ?LINE, A]),
    R = erlcloud_s3:put_object(?BUCKET, Key, Value, [], [{"Content-type", "image/jpeg"}]),

    error_logger:info_msg("~p:~p Uploaded File ~p to S3 ~n", 
              [?MODULE, ?LINE, R]),
    {ok, R}.


 {noproc,
  {gen_server,call,
   [httpc_manager,
    {request,
     {request,undefined,<0.2.0>,0,https,
      {"zacharykessin.s3.amazonaws.com",443},
      "/test",[],put,
      {http_request_h,undefined,"keep-alive",
       "Thu, 15 Mar 2012 14:22:14 GMT",
       undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
       undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
       undefined,undefined,
       ["AWS ","********************",58,
    <<"1O6HYjq8RU8sqtD8oZd1T+bMNCE=">>],
       undefined,undefined,
       "zacharykessin.s3.amazonaws.com",
       undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
       undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
       undefined,[],undefined,undefined,...},
      {"application/octet_stream",
       <<255,216,255,224,0,16,74,70,73,70,0,1,2,1,
     1,44,1,44,0,0,255,225,25,59,69,120,105,...>>},
                                 {http_options,"HTTP/1.1",infinity,true,
                                     {essl,[]},
                                     undefined,false,infinity,false},
                                 "https://zacharykessin.s3.amazonaws.com/test",
                                 [],none,[],1331821334636,undefined,undefined,
                                 false}},
                         infinity]}}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure to run

```
inets:start()
```

somewhere before running your code.

The error you are getting means that there is no such process (`noproc`) registered as `httpc_manager`, which is a part of `inets` library application.